# Question mark instead of number for reference

Tags: bibtex

I an new to Latex, and I am trying to use 'bibtex' to create a reference, I was working in `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex`.

Here is my sample code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin {document}
$$ x_i$$

\section{Introduction}

According to \cite{2006} 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{my_bibtex}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the `.bib` file that I am using.

```
@article{2006,
     jstor_articletype = {research-article},
     title = {The Cross-Section of Volatility and Expected Returns},
     author = {Ang, Andrew and Hodrick, Robert J. and Xing, Yuhang and Zhang, Xiaoyan},
     journal = {The Journal of Finance},
     jstor_issuetitle = {},
     volume = {61},
     number = {1},
     jstor_formatteddate = {Feb., 2006},
     pages = {pp. 259-299},
     url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/3699341},
     ISSN = {00221082},
     abstract = {We examine the pricing of aggregate volatility risk in the cross-section of stock returns. Consistent with theory, we find that stocks with high sensitivities to innovations in aggregate volatility have low average returns. Stocks with high idiosyncratic volatility relative to the Fama and French (1993, Journal of Financial Economics 25, 2349) model have abysmally low average returns. This phenomenon cannot be explained by exposure to aggregate volatility risk. Size, book-to-market, momentum, and liquidity effects cannot account for either the low average returns earned by stocks with high exposure to systematic volatility risk or for the low average returns of stocks with high idiosyncratic volatility.},
     language = {English},
     year = {2006},
     publisher = {Blackwell Publishing for the American Finance Association},
     copyright = {Copyright © 2006 American Finance Association},
    }
```

However, instead of expected `[1]` for reference, I am getting `[?]`, an nothing is listed under references, though the word "References" does show up.

In the youtube [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ifh3NF-k-k) that I was following this case is described. The tutorial did say that sometimes there might this be an issue with creating a reference. To which the author suggest to work in `BibTeX` only, then move to `pdfLaTeX` and then click run a couple of times, and things should work. I did the above, but nothing works for me.

Any ideas how to get my code to work?

**Edit:**

Here are the contents of my `.bbl` file:

```
% Generated by IEEEtran.bst, version: 1.13 (2008/09/30)
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}
\csname url@samestyle\endcsname
\providecommand{\newblock}{\relax}
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\providecommand{\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=0pt\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor}{4}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus
\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor\fontdimen3\font minus
  \fontdimen4\font\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
\typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
\typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
\typeout{** the default language instead.}%
\else
\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
\fi
#2}}
\providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}
\BIBdecl
```

**Edit:**

Here are contents of my `.blg` file.

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: newfile.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
I couldn't open database file my_bibtex.bib
---line 4 of file newfile.aux
 : \bibdata{my_bibtex
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file newfile.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "2006"
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.13 (2008/09/30) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.
```

Done.
(There were 2 error messages)

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Just a little note not concerning the problem: never use `$$..$$` to delimit math in display, but use `\[..\]` instead

Comment: If I run `pdflatex` on your file, then `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` twice I get the expected result.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for you help. I tried what you said, but it is still not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3903/discussion-between-akavall-and-egreg)

Comment: @Akavall: Is your bib file actually called `my_bibtex.bib` and is it in the same folder as the tex file?

Comment: @Caramdir, Yes.

Comment: @Akavall: Well, bibtex seems to be complaining that it cannot find the file.

Comment: @Caramdir, Yes, I am going to check if I have I have the path stuff set correctly...maybe that's it....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you have assigned the key “2006” in your `my_bibtex.bib`. Let's assume your `TeX` file is named `test.tex`. Then you should have ran `bibtex test`. Check that it did not print any error messages.

To further pin down your problem you should add `\nocite{*}` to your `TeX` file. (I always put it right before `\bibliography`.) This makes `bibtex` print all entries in your bibliography, even those which are not explicitly cited in the document.

So this is still about https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61301/creating-a-reference-with-bibtex-beginner. Another guess could have been, that a `bibtex` key can not start with a digit, but I just tried that and it is not a problem.

With the `bibtex` file from the other post I tried to build it and I got this error from `bibtex`:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2011)
The top-level auxiliary file: test10.aux
I couldn't open style file IEEEtran.bst
---line 3 of file test10.aux
 : \bibstyle{IEEEtran
 :                   }
```

I.e. I don't have that `bibtex` style. So you should also check if that style is a valid one which is installed on your system!

...

I can not really believe that you don't get any error messages. After I have downloaded the `IEEEtran.bst` file, everything worked ok. Note that for compiling you need to do

```
pdflatex first_try.tex
bibtex first_try
pdflatex first_try.tex
pdflatex first_try.tex
```

In the first run, `pdflatex` creates the `first_try.aux` file which contains the information about used bibliographies. With that given, `bibtex` can construct the `first_try.bbl` file with the assembled bibliography data. Then `pdflatex` will include it in the document. But as that happens mostly after the point it is referenced, another run of `pdflatex` is required to get a correct reference.

If you still can't solve the problem, please post the output of those commands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes this question is the follow up of my previous post. How do I assign "2006" as key? Where should I put `\nocite{*}` in my `test.tex` file? I am not getting any errors. Given how new I am to LaTex, my gut feeling is that the problem is with me :). Sorry for having problems following.

Answer (score 1):

Your bib file could look like this

```
@BOOK{2006,
  title = {Learning SQL on SQL Server 2005},
  publisher = {O'Reilly},
  year = {2006},
  author = {Sikha Saha Bagui and Richard Earp},
  isbn = {978-059-610-2159}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that if my file has this format, it will not work? What format will work?

Comment: @Akavall: No, he is just giving an example of a correct file with the key “2006”. But as noted above there does not seem to be an issue with yours anyway. You should only have included it in this post as well.