# Unable to load citations

Tags: templates

The following template

```
http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.tgz
```

is supposed to work absolutely fine, however, for some strange reason, it is currently unable to load citations (take as an example the line 36
of file /Chapter1/chapter1.tex):

```
Now I would like to cite the following: \cite{latex} and \cite{texbook}
and \cite{Rud73}.
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In order for citations to be referenced, you need to compile your project with an intermediate `bibtex` command. For example, `latex test`, `bibtex test`, `latex test` (and perhaps another `latex test`). The same goes for `pdflatex`. Did you do this?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Basically, what I do is a) load the file (using the TeXworks application in Linux) and b) press the green button, having selected the pdfLaTeX from the drop-down menu next to the button. So, any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Run `BibTeX` by selecting it from the menu in which you found `pdfLaTeX` and pressing the green button again. Then run `pdfLaTeX` again.

Comment: @IanThompson: Thank you very much! It works now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark instead of number for reference](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/question-mark-instead-of-number-for-reference)