# Unable to load nomenclatures

Tags: templates, nomenclature

Following my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62463/unable-to-load-citations), there is another one issue that stills unanswered.

Once gain, the following template

```
http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.tgz
```

is supposed to work absolutely fine, however, for some strange reason, it doesn't load the nomenclatures page at all. In fact, I can't even figure out where this information is located within the project.

The only related to this issue information I managed to found is the following lines of LaTeX code:

```
% Nomenclature
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
   \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}] }{%             A - Roman
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
     \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%             G - Greek
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
        \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%              R - Superscripts
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
           \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{{%             S - Subscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{{%    X - Other Symbols
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}%              Z - Acronyms
                        {{}}}}}}}}}}
```

which are located in the 8th line of file Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that you're not adding the right `makeindex` command to your build procedure. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14697/how-to-typeset-mathematical-symbols-with-index-etc-always-the-same-way-and-ea/14704#14704) or the `nomencl` documentation, and see if that helps.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Thank you for your answer. I don't believe that this template has a certain issue, but rather, it is my lack of knowledge on how to use the LaTeX works that causes the problem. Anyway.

I am using TeXworks editor. By selecting MakeIndex from the drop-down list and then pressing the green button, I end up with the following message:

Couldn't find input index file thesis nor thesis.idx.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Is that normal?

Comment: Anyone who could help me to sort this problem out?

Comment: I've read [in a German forum](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=70054) that you can add a new procedure for `nomencl` in TeXworks. It must be somewhere under EDIT > PREFERENCES > TYPESETTING  (I haven't worked with TeXworks myself so I can't say more). The forum post shows screenshots which might be helpful.

Comment: You can't just run `makeindex` from the TeXworks button. It doesn't pass the right arguments needed to build the nomenclature. You can do any of the following: see section 2.1 of the [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) documentation and run the makeindex command given there manually, switch editors to something that lets you insert custom commands into the build process (like TeXnicCenter), or use [LaTeXmk](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38204/cross-platform-latex-build-system/38282#38282) to build the nomenclature (assuming your version of TeXworks has a LaTeXmk build option.

Comment: @MikeRenfro make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just run `makeindex` from the TeXworks button. It doesn't pass the right arguments needed to build the nomenclature. You can do any of the following: see section 2.1 of the [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) documentation and run the `makeindex` command given there manually, switch editors to something that lets you insert custom commands into the build process (like TeXnicCenter), or use [LaTeXmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38204/cross-platform-latex-build-system/38282) to build the nomenclature (assuming your version of TeXworks has a LaTeXmk build option.

Answer (score 0):

I use this thesis template too. To run `makeindex` I use the following command.

```
makeindex thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls
```

I also use TexMaker, and I have set up the following command as a custom quick-build.

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | bibtex %.aux | makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls | pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | acroread %.pdf &
```

If running in a terminal, replace % with thesis or whatever your file is called.

Also the template will only create a nomenclature page if you have defined terms in the text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)