# How to use \nocite{*} command in article class without getting question marks in the body of the text?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm having some troubles using the command `\nocite{*}` to avoid citations in the body of my text. I've compiled many times and it keeps showing me question marks at the `\nocite{*}`'s location. No matter what bibliography style I use, it still shows the question marks. Besides, I've tried to use the `listbib`package and didn't have a good result as well.

Please, don't mark this question as already asked because the only one related to this talks about [Other issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/question-mark-instead-of-number-for-reference)

This is (hopefully), the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt ,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb,fancyhdr,fancybox,epsfig,psfrag,amsmath,tabularx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,hmargin={25mm,20mm},vmargin={20mm,20mm}]{geometry} %tamanho letter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title},
publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Hello world
\nocite{key} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname} % or \addbibressource{/jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of your code, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` and recompile the document twice to eliminate the question marks?

Comment: This is the body of my document: [Here](http://imageshack.com/a/img834/8784/cch0.png)

Comment: Yes, I've tried to recompile many times as I could, but it didn't eliminate the question marks @crf

Comment: Please post a compilable example as part of your question - as @Jubobs suggests. The png you link to isn't a complete document.

Comment: @PedroNakasu We don't like links too much, here. Instead, you should make your question self-contained by posting a MWE. Besides, you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: @jubobs I've read your [How to make a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) link but I still don't know how to create a compilable MWE since my issue is related to the bibtex, not to thebibliography environment. Sorry for the signature.

Comment: Part of your work is to isolate the problem first, then post a minimal example that reproduces the problem, and then hope for an answer. Regarding how to make a MWE that involves BibTeX, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Comment: @jubobs Thanks for the patience, I've just edited my question up there, I hope I could show my MWE!

Comment: Possible workaround: Replace `\usepackage{harvard}` with `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\usepackage{har2nat}`.

Comment: @PaulGessler Would you mind adding an official answer here?

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for the reminder; done! :-)

Answer (score 8):

The MWE can be reduced to the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title},
publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Hello world \nocite{key} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which still exhibits the issue. I did not look into the `harvard` package code for the details, but it seems it does not handle the `\nocite` macro consistently with the LaTeX built-in support or other packages.

As a workaround, the document can be migrated to `natbib` while still using all the citation commands provided by `harvard` by replacing

```
\usepackage{harvard}
```

with

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
```

as described in the [`har2nat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/har2nat) [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/har2nat).

Here's the complete revised MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title},
publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Hello world \nocite{key} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

And the resulting output (no question mark! :-) :

[image]